# Who's the subject of this predicate in this letter? (1575 Late April, UK)

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity, elizabethan-english

[Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bQpPfTGYDjQC&dq=%22ensued%20by%22&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q=%22ensued%20by%22&f=false): p 101, *Lives and letters of the Devereux, earls of Essex*, by Walter Bourchier Devereux

> [[p 100](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bQpPfTGYDjQC&dq=%22ensued%20by%22&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q=%22ensued%20by%22&f=false) states that this letter was undated, but the penultimate sentence on p99 (ie the last sentence of the previous letter) contains 1575, so I think that this was the year.] No XVIII.’
>   The Queen to Essex.
>
> Right trusty and well beloved Cousin, greeting. Having
>   seen certain offers and requests made by you unto our Deputy
>   in your letter of the 15th of this present directed to our Council, by the which `you` do not only shew yourself providently
>   careful to avoid the inconvenience that might have ensued by
>   the sudden giving over of the enterprize for the reformation
>   of Ulster, but also, for the preventing of such mischiefs as
>   were likely to ensue thereby, **was** content to spoil yourself of
>   that reputation that birth and desert hath cast upon you,
>   offering to serve under our Deputy there in place not answerable to your state and calling; ...

How do you determine/deduce the subject of the predicate starting with **was**? It can't be the greyed `you`, bcecause`you` requires a plural verb. Yet I still believe that the Queen is referring to Earl, because she is discussing how the Earl wills to forgo his reputation to 'serve under our Deputy' in a place beneath his noble 'state and calling'?

Comment: Is "giving over *or* the enterprize" in the original?

Comment: @TRomano Thank you! I missed that error; I can't spell-check these old writings because otherwise, all the other antiquated spellings would be lost.

Comment: I expect a first-person pronoun, "I".  Having seen your letters, I ...

Comment: @TRomano Thanks. My problem is that exactly! So I also remain mystified.

Comment: Or the royal "we" instead of "I".

Comment: My first thought is that the author got confused while writing the sentence. Surely **yourself** indicates that the subject is **you**. But on second thought, I don't know enough about Elizabethan English to rule out the possibility that **you was** was felt to be grammatical.

Comment: I first thought the subject of the "was" was _the inconvenience_, but that doesn't make sense because of the "spoil _yourself_" that follows it.  I am leaning towards Ben Kovitz's interpretation(s).

Comment: My first guess is that, as yours: "you was".  However, I wonder two things: (1) might it be "your letter of the 15th", which gets us "your letter of the 15th ... was content to spoil yourself of that reputation" or (2) what might a facsimile of the original hand-writing reveal?  This is a transcription of a letter, and errors do creep in.

Answer (score 2):

Could the subject be *"you"*? Historically, ["you was"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/historical-usage-of-was-were-with-you) was used occasionally for the "singular you", but I am surprised Queen Elizabeth used it. The OED says that this usage was widespread "in the late 17th and early 18th centuries"; this is earlier than that, but it could already have been in occasional use.

The structure is:

> by the which you do not only shew yourself providently careful ..., but also ... was content to spoil yourself of that reputation ...

If you replace the *"was"* by *"were"*, then it would be clear that the subject of *"were"* is *"you"*. Since *"you was"* was in use at that time for "singular you" (which previously had been a plural pronoun), it seems likely that this is an instance of *"you was"*.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that is a monster of a sentence!

I cannot see any subject that would apply to "was". My first thought was that an "I" had been dropped, which is sometimes done to abbreviate letters. But "I" makes no sense there, and "we" is used later.

I suspect that either the publisher or the author made a mistake, and that "was" should not be there. The "not only" clause makes more sense without it:

> ...you do **not only** shew yourself **providently careful**..., **but also**, ... **content** to spoil yourself of that reputation that birth and desert hath cast upon you...

In modern English, this would mean something like:

> You have shown yourself to be not only careful to avoid trouble, but also content to take a job that is beneath you for the sake of duty.

Comment: The letter was written by Queen Elizabeth. Surely she could not err in grammer.

Comment: Perhaps not, but Walter Devereux could certainly have erred in transcription.